# Application reports timeouts. However nginx has no record or log

Tags: nginx, amazon-web-services, django, uwsgi, amazon-elb

We are serving Django via nginx/uwsgi. We use AWS ELB behind a VPC.

This is a webservice to Mobile clients.

We had reports of timeouts during development so we have added a concept of a request_id to every request

1. client generates request id
2. sends GET /request?_request_id=ABDFEFE
3. if an error occurs, the error is reported to the server along with the request id

The problem I am having now is that I am getting error reports of Timeouts that have
occurred in the wild. However the associated request_ids do not show up in any nginx or uwsgi log.

I am a little suspicious of the amazon elastic load balancer. However I cannot be sure. Since it is a timeout we have no ELB headers to look at, or status code or response body or anything.

We use newrelic to monitor our backend. Occasionally it logs a 'slow transaction' of 3-4 seconds. (Nothing like the 30sec timeouts that are typical with most client libs)

The actual question: Where to look next? According to me and the data I have on the server NOTHING is actually wrong, however the timeouts persist. At this point I dont even know how to begin debugging this. The app servers are running at like 10% capacity (wrt to mem and cpu) Slow sql queries are being logged 
(with nothing interesting there either)

(I am also looking into client side error separately)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Given the clients are mobile devices it's possible the issue isn't you or the ELB.

AWS ELBs don't just drop traffic on the floor; or at least not without letting you know. If the issue is in the ELB then you should see that reflected in the ELB metrics; ELB_5XX or Spillover would be the metrics I would check first in a case like this one. It's unlikely given that your monitoring is indicating that the service is online, though.